# Why doesn't Command-T in MacVim find a file?

Tags: vim, macvim

I opened my rails project in MacVim using:

```
cd ~/development/book-examples/agile_web_dev_rails/worked_examples/depot
mvim .
```

I'm trying to use Command-T to find `./test/fixtures/products.yml`; however, I'm having no success. The screenshot below shows that:

1. NERDTree can see `./test/fixtures/products.yml`
2. Typing `test/` into Command-T doesn't even show the `fixtures` directory

Any thoughts on why `fixtures/products.yml` isn't found by Command-T?

[image: Command-T Results]

### Update

If I open just the `test` directory in MacVim instead of the entire Rails project using:

```
cd ~/development/book-examples/agile_web_dev_rails/worked_examples/depot/test
mvim .
```

Then, Command-T is able to find `fixtures/products.yml`.

Answer (score 8):

The reason is that you have lots of files in the directory you are in. By default plugin reads 10 000 files. You can change this value in your .vimrc:

`let CommandTMaxFiles = 20000`

It's useful if you work on project which contains tons of files (like Rails).
However it's always better to set current dir within VIM with `:cd` command to make plugin work faster.
You can check where you are with `:pwd` command.

Comment: Excellent. Fixed my issue too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to your question, but you ought to look at [Rails.vim](http://rails.vim.tpope.net/), this allows you to navigate through your app using conventient commands like :Rfixture products (complete with tab completion).